# Android notification area style

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-notifications

I am developing an android application which shows a download progress bar in notification area. But I need to style the progress bar like its normal styling.

I mean the default style for KitKat is as follows

[image]

But in my case its showing like this. Can any one please give me an advise how to get the style ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Easiest way: Change your target API.

Comment: notification has contentView and bigContentView properties check them out.
try creating a RemoteViews and assigning that to your notification as `notification.contentView=createdRemoteViews`

Answer (score 0):

See if you go with diff diff API then you will get diff diff style of that if you want to unique for all then better to go with custom notification bar style

I will give a link for that go with this:

http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/display-progress.html

And this is a good example:

http://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2011/09/03/android-notification-uploading-progressbar/